# PHP OOP extend class or pass it as parameter

Tags: php, class, oop, memory

i am confused a little, well for a long time, i've used PHP classess in this way:

```
class A {
   private $temp;

   public function __construct() {
       for($i=0; $i<=300000; $i++) { $this->temp[ $i ] = "Nedzad Alibasic"; }
   }
}
```

and then another class which contains parameter in construct where i would pass class A as declared model:

```
class B {
   private $a;
   public function __construct($a) { $this->a = $a; }
}
```

And everything was fine, i could easy refer to `class A` by `$b->a->somefunction();` but always it seemed to me, when i allocate A class to B, i would charge extra memory, because i passed the whole class? **But how do i see it, there's almost no difference between passing and extending class?**

I mean, is there someone who can lead me why should i switch from this way to `class B extends A { /** code **/ }` when there's almost no difference in memory?

Or there's something else usefull i could use with extends, but can't use within passing class as parameter.

Best regards.

Comment: Extending A will create a brand new class, B, based on A..If you pass A instead, it will not create a new version of A, but rather use the existing instance as a reference. If you then pass A to yet another class, like C, both B and C will use the same instance of A. So which way you go with, depends on what you need.

Comment: I am happier with my way, i guess that's it.. I just needed confirmation i do not missing something :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of extending instead of wrapping inside an attribute of the class is that, when you extend, you are saying that B is also of type A, which means that everywhere in your code where needs an A class, B could be used if B extends from A.

```
<?php
class A {
    private $temp;

    public function __construct() {
        for($i=0; $i<=300000; $i++) { $this->temp[ $i ] = "Nedzad Alibasic"; }
    }

    public function getTemp(){
        return $this->temp;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

function showFirstElementOfTemp($object){
    if($object instanceof A){
        echo $object->getTemp()[0];
    }else{
        echo "Not an A";
    }
}

$b = new B();

showFirstElementOfTemp($b); //Outputs "Nedzad Alibasic"
```

As you can see, this works, because B is an A, and passing B as a parameter in a function where we check the instance and ensure we have a type of A, B is also accepted.

Other than that, wrapping an A for having access to it's methods and attributes is the same, except that you won't get this hierarchy of types that you have with inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, you were opened my eyes a little now.

Comment: I have one fast question, should `child B` call `parent::__construct();` if the parent were declared already out of class? Somewhere in `index.php` before `class B` was called?

Comment: If you implement the `__construct()` method from a class which inherits another, the upper construct from his parent won't get called, and you need to do it manually using the `parent` keyword.
This allows you to override the constructor parent or extend it's functionality.

I don't know if I answered you correctly. Clarify me a little if I answered wrong.

Comment: What do i mean, if i declare `$a = new A();` and after it, i call `$b = new B();` should there be `parent::__construct();` in B, because i called parent before, and it's construct was executed. Or i have to call `parent::__construct();` inside every child that extends it's parent to work properly.

Comment: Yes, because they are two diferent instances, and do not share the same values for attributes. So, when you declare `new A()` it will not have any effect on any other declaration, not even for other As or other Bs. So, when you do `new B()` you need to call the super construct to have the same value that a new A would have.

Answer (score 2):

What you're used to doing is a form of composition, whereas using `extend` is, of course, inheritance. Generally composition is to be [preferred over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). You should probably continue doing. There are loads of resources describing the pros and cons of [composition versus inheritance](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=when%20to%20use%20inheritance%20over%20composition); picking a good one is tricky but I recommend you read a few of them.

Comment: Thank you for links